# IBM Container にストレージボリュームをマウントするには

Tags: bluemix

[ドキュメント](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_optional.html#container_volumes)を参考に、単一コンテナに対して、ストレージボリュームをマウントしようとしていますが成功しません。
もし成功している方がいれば、次の作業に誤りがないかご指摘いただけますでしょうか。

1. ストレージボリュームの作成

   `cf ic volume create volume01`
2. ストレージボリュームをコンテナ起動時のオプションに指定

   `cf ic run -v volume01:/data2 --name container01 <コンテナイメージ>`

   ※2．後に container01 に入って /data2 を確認しましたが、存在しませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Web 画面からのコンテナ作成（詳細オプションのボリュームを使用）でも、同じくストレージボリュームの存在を確認することができませんでした。
ただし、画面には『ボリューム：volume01:/data2』と表示されています。